# Issues with port forwarding with Layer 3 switch

Tags: nat, cisco-ios, cisco-catalyst, ssh, pfsense-2

Since I have upgrade my switch, I have been experiencing issues with port forwarding on my pfSense gateway. I have done some researching on google, but didn't come to any conclusive results.

Background:
My old network configuration was ISP > pfSense > Dell PowerConnect 2016 Switch > Client. This switch was 10/100 Mb, unmanaged plug and play.

My new configuration is ISP > pfSense > Cisco Catalyst 3560G > Client. To my understanding this switch has layer three functionality that I am not using. I do not have any VLANS running other than the default VLAN 1. (As far as I know) I do not have ip routing enabled.

In both configurations, pfSense is running pureNAT and I have followed many tutorials on setting up port forwarding assuming I was messing it up somehow (I did reinstall pfSense onto a new HDD).

Since these changes have been made, I have been unable to successfully setup SSH, http, as well as other things. I have run a port scan on my external IP and the ports that I am forwarding in pfSense read as open. However, when I attempt to SSH into the machine that the SSH port is being forwarded to, the connection eventually times out. I have tested SSH locally and there are no issues. Just to be sure, I tested this on multiple machines and VMs with the same results.

As I am new to managed/layer 3 switches, I am looking for someone to guide in in the right direction to figure out why I am incurring this issue.

Switch Config:

```
version 12.2
no service pad
service timestamps debug uptime
service timestamps log uptime
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Main-Switch
!
enable secret 5 ####################
enable password ########
!
no aaa new-model
ip subnet-zero
!
!
!
!
!
!
no file verify auto
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/4
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/5
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/6
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/7
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/8
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/9
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/10
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/11
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/12
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/13
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/14
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/15
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/16
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/17
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/18
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/19
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/20
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/21
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/22
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/23
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/25
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/26
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/27
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/28
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/29
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/30
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/31
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/32
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/33
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/34
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/35
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/36
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/37
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/38
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/39
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/40
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/41
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/42
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/43
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/44
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/45
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/46
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/47
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/48
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/49
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/50
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/51
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/52
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
!
ip classless
ip http server
ip http secure-server
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
line vty 0 4
 password #########
 no login
line vty 5 15
 password #########
 no login
!
!
end
```

Comment: Please post the configuration of the Cisco switch.

Comment: Unless you have changed the configuration of the switch since you bought it (you bought it new right with no configuration changes?) then this is not an issue with the switch so long as it works correctly for internal traffic. I would look at the pfSense rather.

Comment: @waza-ari Switch config was added to the post.

Comment: @waza-ari My LAN in pfSense is also setup to be 192.168.53.0 if that matters

Comment: @ojs Unfortunately due to budget the switch is not new but I have "factory reset" it to the best of my ability. It seems the previous owner deleted the web console files however :(

Comment: The switch right now is doing nothing except forwarding frames. While there are some things that at least should be configured, this is definitely not an issue of the switch, except it is physically defect.

Comment: @waza-ari While I troubleshoot more, what would you recommend be configured?